# If $0<p<q<1$ Prove that $q<p+q-pq<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $0<p<q<1$

Prove that $q<p+q-pq<1$

I'm not sure how to set out a proof for this

Comment: Well, you have two things to prove: $q<p+q-pq$ and $p+q-pq<1$.  Do you have any ideas on either of them?  (The first one is probably easier.)

Comment: The other part comes from noting $p \gt pq$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

What is the sign of $(1-p)(1-q)$?